# White space between content and footer

Tags: html, css

I am working on my first website and when I reduce the width of the browser a white space appears between my content and the footer. At full size everything is fine. Is there a way to make it that the gap doesn't appear?

Apologies if there is more code there than required as this is my first time writing code for a website and i have taught myself.

Any help is greatly appreciated

** Edit**
I have figured the cause of the problem. The image in the div above the footer is shrinking to keep its proportions creating the white space in the div. I was able to resolve the issue by removing the image from the div in the html file. I added the image to the div as a background in CSS and use the following styling to resolve the issue

```
.locally-img {
  width: 60vw;
  height: 60vh;
  background: url(./images/rsz_1locally.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to see exactly what you mean, but there are in general two problems in you code:

1. There is an overuse of height. Too many places you specify height as `max-height`, `height`, `padding-top`. Combining that with overflow should also be limited.
2. When you have repeating blocks of code try to make generic selectors. Instead of selectors like `.item2`, `.item2` etc. make a generic selector like `.item`. The same goes for `.item2 p`. If the `p` inside `.item2` needs to be special that is fine, but if all `p` elements should be styled in the same way, just make one selector link `p {...}`.
3. Setting `padding` or `margin` on text (`p`) to a percentage is hard to control. Use `em` instead.

I have done some of the modifications here, but probably also broken a thing or two.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {}

.main-body {}


/* nav bar */

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 8vh;
  /* background: #b0b6a5; */
  background: #cfe1b9;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 50%;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.burger {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {}
  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 8vh;
    /* background: #b0b6a5; */
    background: #cfe1b9;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .burger {
    display: block;
  }
}

.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}


/* nav bar end */


/* Background image*/

.background {
  background: url(./images/microgreens.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.background-image {
  color: #fff;
}

.b-text {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(44, 44, 43), 0 0 10px rgb(44, 44, 43), 0 0 15px rgb(44, 44, 43);
  /* text-shadow: 0 0 5px #f00, 0 0 10px #f90, 0 0 15px #f00; */
  font-weight: 900;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
}


/* Background image end */


/* Intro  */

.intro {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 5vh;
  margin-right: 5vh;
}

.intro-head {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.about-farm {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: larger;
}


/* intro end */


/* Locally grown */

.image {
  width: 65%;
}

.image-c1 {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.item-c2 {
  width: 35%;
}

.item-c2 h3 {
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding-top: 120px;
}

.item-c2 p {
  text-align: justify;
  margin: .5em;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


/* locally grown end */


/* Microgreens */

/* microgreens end */


/* Mushrooms */

.image3 {
  width: 65%;
}

.mushrooms-img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.item {
  width: 35%;
}

.item h3 {
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.item p {
  text-align: justify;
  margin: .5em;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.mushrooms {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}


/* mushrooms end */


/* footer */

footer {
  background: #cfe1b9;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}


/*  */


/* end of home */


/*  */

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .footer-c {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  footer {
    text-align: center;
  }
  #newsletter,
  .follow-us,
  .footer-information {
    border-bottom: 1.5px solid black;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* Locally */
  .container {
    display: block;
  }
  .image {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .item-c2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .item-c2 h3 {
    padding-top: 17%;
  }
  /* Microgreens */
  .microgreens {
    display: block;
  }
  .image2 {}
  /* Mushrooms */
  .mushrooms {
    display: block;
  }
  .item {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .image3 {}
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="./images/cropped-logo.png" alt="Company Logo" height="100" />
    </div>

    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="./about.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="./shop.html">Shop</a></li>
      <li><a href="./contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="burger">
      <div class="line31"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
      <div class="line4"></div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- Nav bar end -->
  <div class="background">
    <div class="background-image">
      <h1 class="b-text">locally produced farm fresh produce</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Home page Content -->
  <!-- Locally Grown -->
  <div class="main-body">
    <div class="intro">
      <h2 class="intro-head">An Fheirm Bheag</h2>
      <p class="about-farm">
        An Fheirm Beag is a small 20 acre family owned and operated farm. We operate our farm using sustainable practices to help build healthy soil and integrate habitats for wildlife while producing food that is packed full of flavour and nutrition. We offering
        a variety of farm fresh produce including gourmet mushrooms, microgreen and farm fresh eggs. We also grow a beautiful selection of seasonal cut flowers to add colour to your home Check out our shop to see whats available.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="container1">
      <div class="image">
        <img class="image-c1" src="./images/rsz_1locally.png" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="item-c2">
        <h3>Locally Grown</h3>
        <p class="about-locally">
          All of the producer we offer for sale is produced by us on our family farm. All produces is picked within 24-48 hours of sale to ensure our customers get the freshest locally produced food possible.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Locally Grown Ends -->
    <!-- Microgreens -->
    <div class="microgreens">
      <div class="image2">
        <img src="./images/microgreens bowl.jpeg" alt="" class="microgreens-img" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Microgreens</h3>
        <p class="about-micro">
          Microgreens are the young shoots of vegetables and herbs. They ar packed full of vitamins and minerals and make great addition to salads and sandwiches. Microgreens can be juiced,blended to make smoothies or used to garnish any dish. They add amazing
          flavour and vibrant colour to your dish.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Microgreens end -->
    <!-- mushrooms -->
    <div class="mushrooms">
      <div class="image3">
        <img class="mushrooms-img" src="./images/oyster mushroom2.webp" alt="oyster mushrooms" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Gourmet Mushrooms</h3>
        <p class="about-mushrooms">
          Mushrooms are an amazing source of low caloriesource of fiber, protien, vitamins and minerals. Our gourmet mushrooms are a great way to add flavour and texture to your meal while also being low in sodium.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Mushrooms End -->
  <!-- footer -->
  <div class="footer">
    <footer>
      <div class="footer-c">
        <div id="newsletter">
          <h3 class="footer-h2">Keep Updated</h3>
          <p>Sign up to our news letter</p>
          <form action="Newsletter">
            <input class="emial" type="email" placeholder="Your Email Address" />
            <button>submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-information">
          <h3 class="footer-h2">Company Information</h3>
          <ul class="header-list">
            <li class="header-li"><a href="./about.html"> About Us</a></li>
            <li class="header-li">
              <a href="./contact.html"> Contact Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header-li"><a href="#"> Delivery Info</a></li>
            <li class="header-li">
              <a href="./Terms.html">Terms and Conditions</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header-li">
              <a href="./privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="follow-us">
          <h3 class="footer-h2">Follow Us</h3>
          <!-- font awsome logos -->
          <div class="social-link">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/An-Fheirm-Bheag-111391803916594" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i
              ></a>
          </div>
          <div class="social-link">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/fheirm_bheag/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i
              ></a>
          </div>
          <div class="social-link">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCjESt2-mlGHw3rooT_o1SAg"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i
              ></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="copyright">
        <p class="copyr">&copy; Copyright 2021. An Fheirm Bheag</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>

  <!-- footer end -->

  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank for the advice I knew it was a bit of a mess, i am rewriting the code to tidy it up a bit. Im still trying to get the hang of everything, I tried the amended code above but it has broken a few other things.